# URL Encoding - Illegal Character Replacement

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, urlencode

I am doing some URL redirections in a project that I am currently working on. I am new to web development and was wondering what the best practise was to remove any illegal path characters, such as '-? etc.

I'm hoping I don't have to resort to manually replacing each character with their encoded URLs.

I have tried UrlEncode and HTMLEncode, but UrlEncode doesn't cater for the ? and HTMLEncode doesn't cater for '

E.g. If I was to use the following:

```
Dim name As String = "Dave's gone, why?"
Dim url As String = String.Format("~/books/{0}/{1}/default.aspx", bookID, name)

Response.Redirect(url)
```

I've tried wrapping URL like this:

```
Dim encodedUrl As String = Server.UrlEncode(url)
```

And

```
Dim encodedUrl As String = Server.HTMLEncode(url)
```

Comment: A `?` is a valid URL character. What are you trying to do? Can you post examples of input and wanted output?

Comment: I'm using url re-writing and getting the information in a default page. But I keep getting "The page cannot be found" or "Bad Request" when using UrlEncode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for URLs (RFC 1738, Dec. '94) poses a problem, in that it limits the use of allowed characters in URLs to only a limited subset of the US-ASCII character set:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z],
>   the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),"
>   [not including the quotes - ed], and
>   reserved characters used for their
>   reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL."

So I think you need to worry about ?, and on my system

URL Encode; converts: %7e%2fbooks%2f1%2fDave's+gone%2c+why%3f%2fdefault.aspx

Now, are you using any url rewriting into this??

Comment: I am using url re-writing yeh

Comment: There might be problem with rewriting module. Can you tell us which module are you using and your rules for this rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
String.Format("~/books/{0}/{1}/default.aspx", bookID, Server.UrlEncode(name))  

String.Format("~/books/{0}/{1}/default.aspx", bookID, 
    Server.UrlEncodeComponent(name))
```

I think its HttpUtility.UrlEncodeComponent , please see msdn for further information.